# HTML helper syntax for radio button in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I write this code with HTML Helper in ASP.net with HTML helper?

```
<label>
  <input name="form-field-radio" type="radio" class="inverted">
  <span class="text">OF BASIC</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Better using a viewmodel property and write something like this: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RadioButtonProperty, specifiedValue, new { @class = "inverted" })`.

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtonFor(< Expression< Func< TModel,TValue>> expression, object value, object htmlAttributes)

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.gender,"male")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.gender,"female")
```